# How to plot an Ordinary differential equations

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Hey guys I'm using mathematica 5 now, and so new to this software thing. May I know how to plot the direction field using `PlotVectorField[]` and also finding complete solution curve for this equation?

$$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{y}{x}=\frac{4x^2}{y}\cos(x)$$

Please do help or give me any tips if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up `DSolve[]` and `ListVectorPlot[]`. In addition, for this ODE, you should give a boundary condtion.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Mathematica Version 5 is very old. If possible try  to grab a newer one. There has been a lot of improvements since then!

Comment: `DSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]/x + 4 x^2 Cos[x]/y[x], y[a] == b}, y[x], 
  x] // FullSimplify`

Comment: erm can you explain why i need to add y[a] == b ?
cause my lecture didnt say anything about it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
yy[x_, a_, b_] := Evaluate[y[x] /. 
                  DSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]/x + 4 x^2 Cos[x]/y[x], y[a] == b}, y[x], x]]

Manipulate[Plot[yy[x, a, b], {x, -1, 3}, Evaluated -> True], {a, 1, 3}, {b, 1, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]